# d3.geom.contour - endless loop if max(contour levels) > max(data)

Tags: d3.js

When running http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134 with domain

```
  [95, 115, 135, 155, 175, 196]
```

instead of

```
  [95, 115, 135, 155, 175, 195]
```

as in the example, the contouring algorithms goes into an endless loop. This happens when the maximum value of the contour levels (195 and 196 above) is larger than the maximum value of the data being contoured.

You can reproduce the behaviour by using just one contour level as well:

```
  [ 195 ] -> ok
  [ 196 ] -> endless loop
```

An obvious workaround for at least not crashing is to set one value in the dataset to a large value (larger than the maximum contour level) manually. But that's kind of ugly ...

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. I would open an issue on the D3 page.

Comment: This is indeed a bug -- in particular https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/geom/contour/contour.js#L58. What's happening is that you're creating an empty layer for the last domain value and the loop will never terminate (i.e. it will never find a valid starting position). Fixing this would require a change to the interface (in particular passing in additional data to determine whether the grid has been searched exhaustively). I'd suggest simply setting the contour levels depending on the data.

Answer (score 1):

As @LarsKotthoff mentioned, there is no awareness of the extent of the plot area within the standard version of this function.  It is however, a very small module and easily downloaded, modified and integrated with your code.  Here is an example of one way to do it...

```
function Contour (xScale, yScale) {

    function contour(grid, _, _, start) {
        var s = start || _contourStart(grid); // starting point
        if (!s) return;
        var c = [],    // contour polygon
            x = s[0],  // current x position
            y = s[1],  // current y position
            dx = 0,    // next x direction
            dy = 0,    // next y direction
            pdx = NaN, // previous x direction
            pdy = NaN, // previous y direction
            i = 0;

        do {
            // determine marching squares index
            i = 0;
            if (grid(x-1, y-1)) i += 1;
            if (grid(x,   y-1)) i += 2;
            if (grid(x-1, y  )) i += 4;
            if (grid(x,   y  )) i += 8;

            // determine next direction
            // disambiguate
            if (i === 6) {
                dx = pdy === -1 ? -1 : 1;
                dy = 0;
            } else if (i === 9) {
                dx = 0;
                dy = pdx === 1 ? -1 : 1;
            } else {
                // unambiguous cases
                dx = _contourDx[i];
                dy = _contourDy[i];
            }
            // update contour polygon
            if (dx != pdx && dy != pdy) {
                c.push([x, y]);
                pdx = dx;
                pdy = dy;
            }
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        } while (s[0] != x || s[1] != y);

        return c;
    };

// lookup tables for marching directions
    var _contourDx = [1, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0,-1, 1,0, 0,0,0,-1, 0,-1,NaN],
        _contourDy = [0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,1,-1,1,1, 0,-1, 0,NaN];

    var xDomain = xScale.domain(), xMin = xDomain[0], xMax = xDomain[1],
        yDomain = yScale.domain(), yMin = yDomain[0], yMax = yDomain[1];

    function _contourStart(grid) {
        var x = 0, y = 0;
        // search for a starting point; begin at origin
        // and proceed along outward-expanding diagonals
        while (!(x == xMax && y > yMax)) {
            var px;
            if (grid(x,y)) {
                return [x,y];
            }
            //if the left or top limit is reached
            if ((px = x) <= xMin || y >= yMax) {
                //start a new scan line
                //reflect the x ordinate in y=x in range coordinates and saturate
                x = Math.min(x + y + 1, xMax);
                //if x is not saturated, reset to the minimum y value in range coordinates
                //  use basic similar triangles to calculate the new starting point
                //  return to the start of the current line, then add 1
                y = x === xMax ? y === yMax ? yMax - xMax + px + 1 : y - xMax + 1 : yMin;
            } else {
                x = x - 1;
                y = y + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return contour;
};
```

This version is slightly more efficient in searching for the contour starts (it uses it's new-found knowledge of the plot extent to limit it's search to that) and it returns `null` if it fails to find the contour and like the original version, will only return one contour for a given value (it needs to be called multiple times, with different starting points, to faithfully render non-monotonic surfaces).
It doesn't augment the d3 object like the original version but its usage is idiomatic.  For example...

```
  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var contour = Contour(x, y),
    line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d){return x(d[0])})
      .y(function(d){return y(d[1])}),
    contours = svg.selectAll(".isoline")
      .data(bands.map(isoline));
  contours.enter().append("path");
  contours.datum(contour)
    .attr("class", "isoline")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
      return line(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
      return color(bands[i]);
    })
    .style("stroke", isoLines.value());
  contours.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug indeed. But you can avoid this by hard coding in your front end. Keep a check on the data. And set you domain depending on the data max values. What i a musing in my code is something like the following. You can more optimize the code for you scenario. Here is the code

```
var maxval=d3.max(data,function(d){
                return d3.max(d);
            });
            if(maxval==10){
            color=d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([10])
            .range(["red"]);
            }
            if(maxval==20)
                {
                color=d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([10,20])
                .range(["red","#CCFF99"]);
                }
            if(maxval==30)
                {
                color=d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([10,20,30])
                .range(["red","#CCFF99","yellowgreen"]);
                }
            if(maxval==40)
                {
                color=d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([10,20,30,40])
                .range(["red","#CCFF99","yellowgreen","white"]);
                }
```