# D3.js contour plot not working (Possible bug of d3 contour)

Tags: d3.js

I am plotting a d3.js contour plot. I am following the same steps as shown in the link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134 and https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4241134. But the problem is my code is not working. The size of my 2D matrix for contour plot is dx=82 and dy=141. My code is not plotting anything instead its hanging the browser. I wonder is there any size restriction of matrix on the contour plot? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You data isn't much larger then the example you link to and that draws extremely quickly.  Please provide some code or even better an example that reproduces your problem...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/f1VThUpkHxUzxOBXmTCr?p=preview Here  is a plunker. The code works with their data data.json. But it just hangs with my data data2.json. Nothing shows

Comment: I am stuck. I think its a bug may be. Otherwise where is the problem! the same code. Data in the same format, data values are only changed. So why should the browser hang. It can show error. Or the chart data my be out of bound just the axis could be shown

Comment: Interesting... and not in a good way.  Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500586/d3-geom-contour-endless-loop-if-maxcontour-levels-maxdata) will give you a clue?

Comment: Thanks. Probably the bug is not still solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not really a bug, it's just that the data is incompatible with the colour domain you have specified.  For example, the colour domain runs from 95 to 195 and your data is all 10.  So there is no intersection between the data and the contours.  This is the failure mode.

If you change your contour domain or your data so that they intersect it will be fine.

Comment: I know that my data is not compatible with color domain. I was expecting that there will be the axes shown at least. I was going to correct the color domain. But its just going to infinite loop with my data not showing the axes

Comment: Well, OK, you didn't share that knowledge in your question. So... just test the data and throw if it's not compatible perhaps?  You could always ask for your money back :)

Comment: I have found a solution the problem to avoid entering into infinite loop